# Composer Requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. -kreait/laravel-firebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

Composer has been installed with laravel. However, each command is resulting into failing with the error message below.

```
$ composer require kreait/laravel-firebase
Using version ^3.1 for kreait/laravel-firebase
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update kreait/laravel-firebase
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v8.54.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.54 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.54.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v8.0\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: The error message is rather clear. You need the PHP extension `ext-fileinfo`  enabled. Verify that it's enabled in your php.ini . It even lets you know which php.ini it's using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing extension `fileinfo` if you running on windows all you need is to find `php.ini` and uncomment this line

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dl
```

if you run on Linux-based you will need to install it like this

```
sudo apt install php-fileinfo
```

Comment: How do you uncomment this line? I tried to remove it or to add ; in from the of extension=php_fileinfo.dl .

Comment: remove the `;` this is the comment after that restart your apache server

Comment: it works with only extension=php_fileinfo, thanks Joseph